# How to use roblox auth api to user login using username and password

Tags: python, python-requests, roblox

I was trying to login to roblox account through roblox auth api (https://auth.roblox.com/docs#!/Authentication/post_v2_login) with python request library.

```
data = {
    "ctype": "Username",
    "cvalue": "testusername",
    "password": "testpassword"
}

response =  requests.post("https://auth.roblox.com/v2/login", json=data, headers =get_headers())
```

But it response with

```
{"errors":[{"code":2,"message":"You must pass the robot test before logging in.","userFacingMessage":"Something went wrong","fieldData":"{\"dxBlob\":\"Ft9poWGH6MyJP/XR.H0KuG1miZj/UQ47mXaurhf9HAcX8ne+fAxFGsXwMjk+Yn8dsO+7i0R85UhKiKzGnu3TgFWNesUlKXhQ+Ie/ntNEbR807JE8kTdgLoulpu43JPQQlxCU9hZIFryPkU+p+Vymkd2D8o3OW6jdZ1igww0GqLpKUluYHMrF9ULH8oEX3KT5iBDCw3CfVWendM3nAfAgLj42fr8Y9K8z5INY5nscLShCmyw5XlqKCKtctsZTQRsWF0AWueri60GtARaXbLzUQHzobv8XkurBYLY+MNTxdOfi8cEZAyhYhTiseB+qQIZIFNY95rFITHK46qbZwRW11VlziYqXE+HYP1tvkZf886pD+WT9iShBrs15UmEoChGEoJ5sirijiqy2KY5pj2O+hU8LJb5ziG6OaaGg=\",\"unifiedCaptchaId\":\"jgGnfWmwwfhxzGwEH4SVQZ\"}"}]}
```

how to continue from this step? can I get a captcha image from there response data to solve manually? or what they asking to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need the captcha token.
The payload is supposed to be this

```
data = {
"ctype": "Username",
"captchaToken": "CaptchaToken",
"cvalue": "testusername",
"password": "testpassword"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is going on exactly and also don't know this site, but try these:

1. Turn off your VPN or proxy and then try again.
2. This site seems to be written with microservices arch, so they may have another API doc that contains what you need.

I hope that this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're trying to automate logging into Roblox, The problem here is you haven't solved the captcha. The "robot test" they're referring to here is FunCaptcha that's embed onto the login page. If you'd still like to login, you might have to use captcha solving services to get the `captchaToken` and then pass it while logging in.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am getting this after solving fun captcha do you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

you dont need captcha solving services for that, and it isn't like that anymore you would need to grab the captcha token from the captcha metadata by base64decoding it from the login headers and then you use that it's a completely different system.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
http_response_code(400);
die(json_encode(["errors" => [["code" => 400, "message" => "BadRequest"]]]));
} elseif(isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['password']) &&!empty($_GET['username']) &&!empty($_GET['password'])) {
$u = $_GET['username'];
$p = $_GET['password'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://auth.roblox.com/v2/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
json_encode([
'ctype' => 'username'
'cvalue' => 'Roblox'
'password' => 'Roblox'
'userid' => '1'
'accountBlob' => '' //BLOB FROM CAPTCHA remove this as it is json not php
'CaptchaToken' => '' //captcha token you can get from headers base64decode
'CaptchaId' => '' // my bad if this isnt what its called im writing this from school 
put the unifiedCaptchaId there
]));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($output);
curl_close();
//thats all i can give you just a little hint you cant use python anymore as it is too complex
}
?>
```